# Llenar un listview con Asynctask mediante metodo GET

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

el asunto es que tengo una clase donde obtengo los datos desde **MYSQL** la comunicación entre PHP y la base esta funcionando (lo pobre con postman). El problema es que no se como incorporar un LISTVIEW para que muestre los datos.

```
 private class AsyncRetrieve extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(VerPreguntas.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/Verpregunta/mostrarpre.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }


                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("")) {
          mostrar.setText(result.toString());
        }else{
            // you to understand error returned from doInBackground method
            Toast.makeText(VerPreguntas.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

}
```

entiendo que esta incorporación estará en `onPostExecute`
Saludos!

Comment: Tu listview tiene un custom adapter? O es uno simple?

Comment: @sioesi es simple ...

Comment: Puedes mostrar que imprime result.toString()?

Comment: [{"0":"7","id":"7","1":"Te gusta el pan ?","pregunta":"Te gusta el pan ?"},{"0":"6","id":"6","1":"Te gusta el futbool ?","pregunta":"Te gusta el futbool ?"},{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"Te gusta el pan ?","pregunta":"Te gusta el pan ?"},{"0":"8","id":"8","1":"Te gusta el futbool ?","pregunta":"Te gusta el futbool ?"}]  esto imprime en el Toast o el Textview

Comment: Que dato de ese json quieres mostrar en tu listview? Alguno en particulaf como "pregunta"?

Comment: La verdad solo necesito mostrar la pregunta, sin el id, en este ejemplo lo hice así en modo prueba, pero debo modificar la consulta ...

Comment: @FelixBeeb y aún no realizas el parser para este .json?

Comment: @Elenasys Lo que tengo es la conexion entre PHP y MSQL, aun no incorporo el listview ni el parser. Como he comentado me arroja ese mensaje de arriba

Comment: @FelixBeeb la respuesta es un JsonArray, tiene que ser parseado y los datos agregarlos al Adapter, este Adapter es el que relacionarias a tu ListView. Sería bueno agregaras tu ListView para que pruebes, agregue una respuesta que espero te sea de ayuda de todo el proceso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como es un `Listview` normal puedes hacer :

Como recibes un arreglo Json, lo primero es obtener ese array en un `JSONArray` , despues creamos un `ArrayList` del tipo String ya que solo vamos a mostrar el valor de pregunta. Y despues recorremos ese `JSONArray` y agregamos a nuestro `ArrayList` el valor de pregunta. Finalmente seteamos el `ArrayAdapter` al `Listview`

```
try{
    ArrayList<String> listaPreguntas = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
    for(int i=0;i<(jArray.length());i++){
        JSONObject json_obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String pregunta = json_obj.getString("pregunta");
        listaPreguntas.add(pregunta);
        Context context = TuActivity.this;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  listaPreguntas);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
   System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Este iría en el onPostExecute, no es así ?

Comment: Exacto! @FelixBeeb

Comment: La clase no puede resolver el constructor del arrayAdapter :/

Comment: Es por el this, tienes que poner, como esta dentro de una tarea asincrona debes tener esto Context context = tuactivity.this;

Comment: Actualice @FelixBeeb

Comment: Sigo sin entender esos votos negativos cuando no corresponden -.-!!!

Comment: Amigo yo no he votado negativo, de hecho me has ayudado !

Comment: Si lo se amigo! No era para ti, pero hay gente que ocupa los votos de forma erronea, tal como tu dices mi respuesta  te ayudo en cambio hay gente que vota negativo solo porque si, en fin, haters :P ! Saludos y que bueno que se haya solucionado tu inquietud

Comment: Si comprendo el punto jaja y gracias nuevamente, me despido, saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Al terminar tu `AsyncTask`, recibes una respuesta

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("")) {
          mostrar.setText(result.toString());
        }else{
            // you to understand error returned from doInBackground method
            Toast.makeText(VerPreguntas.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

la cual como comentas es un json, si revisamos la estructura, es un `JsonArray` que tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta respuesta la tendrás que parsear para obtener el valor que deseas, en este caso la pregunta, pero esta pregunta la tienes que almacenar en un arraylist para alimentar tu adapter:

```
    List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(respuesta); 
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
        preguntas.add(pregunta);
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Para mostrar los datos tienes que crear un `Adapter` con el cual llenaras el `ListView`:

```
   //crear el Adapter.
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
            //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

Ahora integramos todo el código en el método `onPostExecute()`, el proceso es recibir la respuesta (`result`) evaluar si contiene datos, si es así se parsea convirtiendo primeramente a `JSONArray` y las preguntas las almacenas en un ArrayList, al tener tu `ArrayList` creas un `Adapter` y al final asignas este `Adapter` a tu `ListView` :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("")) {  //No hay datos
          mostrar.setText(result.toString());
        }else{ //Existen Datos

    List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();

       //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
       try {
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result); 
          for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
              String pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
              preguntas.add(pregunta);
          }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }

         //crear el Adapter.
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
        //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // you to understand error returned from doInBackground method
            Toast.makeText(VerPreguntas.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Gracias a todos, ha funcionado !

Comment: @FelixBeeb excelente Felix!

Comment: Lo único que falto al tu código es agregar los Try si no dará error. Gracias por la ayuda y el tiempo. saludos !

Comment: @FelixBeeb ya esta listo, ahh me quitaste la respuesta! =|

Comment: Nuevamente gracias !